# Recycle view not populating with json

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, android-volley

my recyclerview is not populating with the json here is my my fragment code which contain recyclerview,i am getting json data from php via volley library please help me out. i have posted fragment code,adapter code as well as logcats of my app.

```
public String get_events="urlfordata";
    public RequestQueue requestQueue;
    public StringRequest stringRequest;
    public String college_name;
    public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public LinearLayoutManager llm;
    public List<events> events = new ArrayList<events>();
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_home,container,false);
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.neostat_home_recycleview);


            SharedPreferences sha1 = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("user_data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            college_name = sha1.getString("college_name",null);
            llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
            stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, get_events, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                        for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            events = new ArrayList<>();
                            events.add(new events(jsonObject.getString("title"),jsonObject.getString("image")));
                            System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                        }



                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            })
            {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
                    hashMap.put("college_name","");
                    return hashMap;
                }
            };

            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


            events_adapter adapter = new events_adapter(events);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


            return v;
        }
    }
```

my adapter:-

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by cheta on 5/18/2016.
 */
public class events_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<events_adapter.EventHolder> {


    List<events>  events;
    events_adapter(List<events> events)
    {
        this.events =events;

    }
    @Override
    public EventHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.event_cardview,parent,false);
        EventHolder pvh = new EventHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(EventHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.textView.setText(events.get(position).title);
        Context context = holder.imageView.getContext();
        Picasso.with(context).load(events.get(position).image).fit().into(holder.imageView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return events.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public static class EventHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;
        CardView cardView;

        EventHolder(View v)
        {
            super(v);
            cardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.events_home_cardview);
            imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.events_home_image);
            textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.events_home_title);

        }

    }
}
```

my log:-

```
05-18 20:56:41.538 26693-26693/com.ph.com.neostat W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.ph.com.neostat-1/lib/x86
05-18 20:56:41.598 26693-26703/com.ph.com.neostat I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 15897(1349KB) AllocSpace objects, 8(176KB) LOS objects, 72% free, 1026KB/3MB, paused 7.468ms total 52.247ms
05-18 20:56:41.741 26693-26693/com.ph.com.neostat W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
05-18 20:56:41.835 26693-26988/com.ph.com.neostat D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                                    [ 05-18 20:56:42.023 26693:26693 D/         ]
                                                                    HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaa97fda0, tid 26693


                                                                    [ 05-18 20:56:42.157 26693:26988 D/         ]
                                                                    HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaec12aa0, tid 26988
05-18 20:56:42.355 26693-26988/com.ph.com.neostat I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-18 20:56:43.596 26693-26988/com.ph.com.neostat W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-18 20:56:43.596 26693-26988/com.ph.com.neostat W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaa75e620, error=EGL_SUCCESS
05-18 20:56:43.784 26693-26693/com.ph.com.neostat I/Choreographer: Skipped 99 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-18 20:56:45.295 26693-26693/com.ph.com.neostat I/Choreographer: Skipped 86 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-18 20:56:45.621 26693-26699/com.ph.com.neostat W/art: Suspending all threads took: 38.568ms
05-18 20:57:25.469 26693-26988/com.ph.com.neostat W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-18 20:57:25.470 26693-26988/com.ph.com.neostat W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xab27ec00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
05-18 20:57:27.763 26693-26988/com.ph.com.neostat E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb2eef960
05-18 20:57:36.429 26693-26988/com.ph.com.neostat W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-18 20:57:36.429 26693-26988/com.ph.com.neostat W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xab27ef40, error=EGL_SUCCESS
05-18 20:57:37.093 26693-26988/com.ph.com.neostat E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb2eef8f0
05-18 20:57:43.260 26693-26699/com.ph.com.neostat W/art: Suspending all threads took: 79.213ms

                                                         --------- beginning of system
05-18 20:57:44.483 26693-26693/com.ph.com.neostat W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for classified_home{9dbcc53 #0 id=0x7f0c006a android:switcher:2131492970:1} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
05-18 20:57:44.747 26693-26988/com.ph.com.neostat W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-18 20:57:44.748 26693-26988/com.ph.com.neostat W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xab27ef60, error=EGL_SUCCESS
05-18 20:57:45.461 26693-26988/com.ph.com.neostat E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb2eef5e0
05-18 20:57:48.924 26693-26693/com.ph.com.neostat W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=561.48926, y[0]=977.46094, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=7782899, downTime=7776256, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
05-18 20:57:48.924 26693-26693/com.ph.com.neostat W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=561.48926, y[0]=977.46094, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=7782899, downTime=7776256, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
05-18 20:57:48.924 26693-26693/com.ph.com.neostat W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=561.48926, y[0]=977.46094, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=7782899, downTime=7776256, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
05-18 20:57:48.924 26693-26693/com.ph.com.neostat W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=561.48926, y[0]=977.46094, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=7782899, downTime=7776256, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
```

Comment: sorry...kindof new to android studio.. :)... System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("title")); that was juct for checking in logs whether php is returning json properly..

Comment: `System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("title"));` [of course ... not](http://ideone.com/PPHi95)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Selvin said in the comments, keep in mind below things.

**1.** `events_adapter adapter = new events_adapter(events);` **-** for RecyclerView set a adapter after getting data (http response) or if you set before that, call `adpter.notifyDataSetChanged();` so that `RecyclerView` will refresh views.

**2.** `events = new ArrayList<>(); in loop` **-** On each loop you are creating  `events` object, while you are suppose to create only once.

**3.**  Instead of `System.out.println("blah blah blah");` use [Android Logging API - Log](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)

Make these below changes to `onResponse` method

**Solution 1** 
call this line `events = new ArrayList<>();`  before making request or creating adapter instance.

```
for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);    
    events.add(new events(jsonObject.getString("title"),jsonObject.getString("image")));
    Log.i("TAG","Title "+jsonObject.getString("title"));
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Solution 2**

```
events = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    events.add(new events(jsonObject.getString("title"),jsonObject.getString("image")));
    Log.i("TAG","Title "+jsonObject.getString("title"));
}
events_adapter adapter = new events_adapter(events);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: in point 3. there is an error ... if he would use first option he shouldn't do  `events = new ArrayList<>();` in `onResponse` ... (obviously if he would do that, the `events` would point to the different `ArrayList` then used in adapter, so obvioulsy `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` wouldn't work)

Comment: yeah, now its ok ... but there is already many similar questions on SO

Comment: @Selvin as he is new to android.. I taught to explain in details and I did **:) :)**